Encrypted token in azure, decrypt encrypted token
I use angular with a bff (spring boot 3.2) and api with  spring boot 3.2.
Bff use spring cloud for authentication. Angular get token from Bff and send it to the api backend  in "Authorization" header.
That work fine, now I search to use an encrypted token.
I wonder if azure can return a encrypted token.. and in the api backend this encrypted token could be validated automatically?
otherwise i would need to decrypt the token where I supposed to do this in my Security config?
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig {

    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors(cors -> cors.configurationSource(request -> {
                      CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
                        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
                        return configuration;
                    }))
                    .csrf().disable().httpBasic().disable().headers().xssProtection().and()
                    .and().headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                    .and().authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/swagger-ui.html", "/actuator/**").permitAll().and()
                    .apply(AadResourceServerHttpSecurityConfigurer.aadResourceServer())
                    .and().authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();nticated();

        http.build();
    }
}


Provided that you're using https in your communication between endpoints, there should be no need to encrypt the token.
JWTs contain three sections. A header, a payload, and a signature, separated by dots. A bearer token used for authorization is usually base64 encoded. You can base64 decode the token and see the different sections.
The signature serves as tamper protection. HTTPs Transport Layer Security (TLS) serves for data privacy in transit. You shouldn't need to store the token anywhere, other than in transient session memory.
The signature is, basically, an encrypted hash of the token header + payload. When the Microsoft Identity Platform generates a token, it will carry out a hash function - usually SHA256. It then encrypts this hash with a secret key (private portion of a cryptographic key-pair) according to the RSA algorithm. The result is a HMACSHA256. It's the signature inside the token which is encrypted.
If anyone were to alter the content of the body (which contains the claims), for example, in an attempt to impersonate a different user, or to add more claims/permissions, the signature would become invalid, since the hash of the header + payload would be completely different. Even with just the slightest modification.
Your backend is able to validate the signature by using the token-signing public key, which Microsoft publishes for anyone to see. It decrypts the signature within the token, carries out its own hash, and compares that to what is in the token. If they match then the relying party (your backend, or possibly other apps or APIs, such as Graph) can be sure the token has not been forged or tampered with.

goal is the user should not be able to read the playload of the token...

There's no built-in support for token encryption. It is assumed that the user profile information is safe to be viewed by the individual users themselves. What you could do is return an identifier claim only, give the backend app permissions for User.Read.All, and get the other claims from Graph API. This isn't very efficient though.
